# Need to perform bulk delete on Search documents -- routinely getting "took too long to respond" errors

Tags: google-app-engine

I perform a cron job where I need to update my search indices. As part of updating, I delete old documents with this code:

```
while True:
    results = index.search(search.Query(
            query_string="locationID="+location_id,
            options=search.QueryOptions(
                limit=100,
                cursor=cursor,
                ids_only=True)))
    cursor = results.cursor
    doc_ids = [tmp_result.doc_id for tmp_result in results]
    index.delete(doc_ids)
    if not cursor: # if cursor is None, meaning no more results
        break
```

I am relatively routinely seeing this error in my logs:

```
DeadlineExceededError: The API call search.DeleteDocument() took too long to respond
and was cancelled.
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my deletion code that I'm seeing this error pop up?

**Edit**:

Is this just a random error that will show up from time to time? If so, should I just implement a redo with an exponential backoff like so:

```
def delete_doc_ids(doc_ids, retries):
    success = False
    time_to_sleep = 2**retries*0.1 #100 ms
    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
    retries+=1
    try:
        index.delete(doc_ids)
        success = True
        return success, retries
    except:
        logging.info("Failure to delete documents. Retrying in %s seconds"%time_to_sleep)
        return success, retries
    # because this step fails a lot, keep running in a while loop until it works with exponential backoff
    deletion_finished = False
    retries = 0
    #keep trying until deletion_finished returns true on an expontential backoff
    while not deletion_finished:
        deletion_finished, retries = delete_doc_ids(doc_ids,retries)
```

**Edit 2:**

What is the default deadline alluded to [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/indexclass)? I dug through the RPC source files and can't find it.

Comment: I'm still facing this issue in 2016. I could empty an index but said index will then emit the "taking too long" error when searches are sent to it. To solve the problem, I built a new index and switch all searches to this new index. The old index is emptied and left unused.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the job to the taskqueue, which has a much longer deadline (10 minutes), or to a custom module, which can run indefinitely.